# How to show records from one table based on foreign key value in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm trying to create a view containing a list of students attending a particular course. A student can attend more than one course, so I have a students (kursist) table and a course_student (kursus_kursist) table in my database.
The course_student table has a student_id set as a foreign key referencing student.student_id.

Controller:

```
// GET: hold/protokol
public ActionResult Protokol(int? id)
{
var kursus_kursist = db.kursus_kursist.Include(k => k.kurser).Include(k => k.kursister);
return View(kursus_kursist.ToList());
}
```

I've tried doing:

```
// GET: hold/protokol
public ActionResult Protokol(int? id)
{
var kursus_kursist = db.kursus_kursist.where(kursus_kursist.kursus_kursist_id = id).Include(k => k.kurser).Include(k => k.kursister);
return View(kursus_kursist.ToList());
}
```

But I get a "cannot use local variable 'kursus_kursist' before it is assigned", which I understand, but how would I go about filtering the results, so they only include the records from k.kursister that match the id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is supposed to be a lambda:

```
where(x => x.kursus_kursist_id == id)
```

here `x` is of the same type as the `kursus_kursist` variable.

Comment: Thanks Andrei, that was it!